# API Platform Symfony : Only getting 30 results (pagination)

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using a Symfony API with an Angular client. When trying to get the data from a table Quotation I only get 30 results max when I want to get everything. I'm using Sellsy on the API. In the SellsyService.php I guess this function is called when I tried to get Quotations:

```
public function getQuotations()
    {
        $devisRequest = array(
            'method' => 'Document.getList',
            'params' => array(
                'doctype' => "estimate",
                'pagination' => array(
                    'nbperpage' => 4999,
                ),
                'search' => array(
                    //'steps' => ['sent','accepted']
                    'steps' => explode(
                        ",",
                        "draft,due,payinprogress,paid,late,sent,read,accepted,contested,expired,advanced,partialinvoiced,invoiced,stored,spent,partialspend,refused"
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
        $devislist = $this->sellsy->requestApi($devisRequest);

        return $devislist;
    }
```

I don't really know where to look, I didn't develop this API. When looking for "30" in the project, I can see this in cache:

```
    'api_platform.eager_loading.max_joins' => 30, 
    'api_platform.collection.pagination.items_per_page' => 30,
```

I don't know if it has something to do with my problem. Here's the config api_platform.yaml:

```
api_platform:
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            apiKey:
                name: Authorization
                type: header
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

Where should I like for this 30 limitation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

API Platform has [pagination](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/).

As you guessed it, by default it's 30.

> API Platform Core has native support for paged collections. Pagination
> is enabled by default for all collections. Each collections contains
> **30 items per page**.

So you have multiple choice to solve your problem.

1. Client side should use your pagination. So nothing to change in your backend but just query a page when looking at your quotations.

Otherwise, you can update your configuration to disable pagination.

[From the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/):

**Disabling the Pagination Globally**

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    defaults:
        pagination_enabled: false
```

**Disabling the Pagination For a Specific Resource**

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Quotation.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"pagination_enabled"=false})
 */
class Quotation
{
    // ...
}
```

[You could also let the client decide.](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/#disabling-the-pagination-client-side)

Or if you don't want to disable it, but increase the number of item per page:

**Changing the Number of Items per Page Globally**

```
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    defaults:
        pagination_items_per_page: 100 # Default value
```

**Changing the Number of Items per Page For a Specific Resource**

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Quotation.php

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={"pagination_items_per_page"=100})
 */
class Quotation
{
    // ...
}
```

There are other things you can do such as partial pagination or changing the number of items per page client-side, but I advise you to just look into the [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/pagination/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I chose to disable the pagination just for Quotation for now, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Just a quick question, I'm trying to use the query parameter pagination. I enabled the pagination on Quotation because I need it at some places. So I'm trying to do what they say in the doc: /api/quotations?pagination=false but the pagination still seem to be working. I also added in the api_platform.yaml `collection:   pagination: 
  enabled_parameter_name: pagination` Should I use partial pagination to do this?

Comment: To be able to use the `pagination` query parameter you need to configure `pagination_client_enabled: true`, look into **Disabling the Pagination Client-side**

Comment: I get the error `Unrecognized option "defaults" under "api_platform".`

Comment: You want to do it just for quotation right ? you can use `  * @ApiResource(attributes={"pagination_client_enabled"=true})` to target only this entity